# Registry Key requires double deletion

Tags: c#, winapi, registry

Deleting some registry entries under HKCR with admin permissions. For the vast majority of keys this works fine, but some keys are not deleted despite `DeleteSubKeyTree` returning success and procmon even showing the RegDeleteKey call.

Simplified code:

```
using var baseKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"WOW6432Node\clsid",
    RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree,
    RegistryRights.EnumerateSubKeys | RegistryRights.QueryValues |
    RegistryRights.ReadKey | RegistryRights.Delete);
baseKey!.DeleteSubKeyTree("someClsid", true); // no exception
// but:
Debug.Assert(baseKey.OpenSubKey("someClsid") is null); // assertion is triggered!
baseKey!.DeleteSubKeyTree("someClsid", true); // again no exception
Debug.Assert(baseKey.OpenSubKey("someClsid") is null); // now it is fine.
```

Looking at procmon traces the last entry for the clsid is:

```
RegDeleteKey    HKCU\Software\Classes\WOW6432Node\CLSID\someClsid   SUCCESS 
RegCloseKey HKCU\Software\Classes\WOW6432Node\CLSID\someClsid   SUCCESS
```

so the native call is registered. No other program recreates the key (or at least there is no procmon log entry for it).

Executing `DeleteSubKeyTree` again causes the key to disappear for good.

This is reproducable for a handful of keys, but other keys (also under wow6432node) work fine, so I don't think this is related to redirection.

Windows 10 64bit
.NET Core 5.0 running as x64 code

Any ideas how one could debug such an issue?

Comment: Did you read the documentation on [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/hkey-classes-root-key), specifically the section that starts with *"If an application is run with administrator rights \[...\]"*?

Comment: @IInspectable So the issue was that there exists a registry key both under Local Machine and Current User and the first deletion obviously only deletes the CU one. Didn't think about that (ah COM is always so much fun). Do you want to write that as an answer?

Comment: Note that you should not be accessing `Wow6432Node` directly. To access 32bit Registry keys in a 64bit app, use a 32bit Registry view instead, eg: `var classesRootKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.ClassesRoot, RegistryView.Registry32); var baseKey = classesRootKey.OpenSubKey("CLSID", ...);`